# Как получить название индекса в массиве?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, angularjs

Есть массив:

```
$scope.storeList = [{
  'id':101,
  'name':"indhu"
},{
  'id':102,
  'name':"selvin"
},{
  'id':103,
  'name':"indhu1"
}];

console.log("",$scope.storeList[2]);
```

Выведет мне: Object {id: 103, name: "indhu1"}

А как получить именно название "ID" или "NAME"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(Object.keys($scope.storeList[2]));
```

Comment: Спасибо, подошло.